# Zipping two lists, cycling through the shorter one

Tags: python, list, loops, concatenation

```
a = ["1", "2", "3"] 
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] 
desired_output = ["1a", "2b", "3c", "1d", "2e"]
```

Hi all, I want to combine `a` and `b` into a new list where `b` could be any length, but I only want to cycle through the sorted values of `a`.

(N.B. I've tried using `zip_longest` where the `fillvalue=cycle` through list `a`... but would this be the right way to go about it?)

Tips? 
Thanks.
Dan.

Comment: Why is `[x + y for x, y in zip(cycle(a), b)]` sloppy?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
from itertools
a = ["1", "2", "3"]
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
[x + y for x, y in zip(itertools.cycle(a), b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use some modular arithmetic to wrap the indices of the shorter list until it's done so as many times as needed to match the length of the longer list.

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['a','b','c','d','e']

desired_output = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    a_index = i % len(a)
    index = a_index + i
    val = a[a_index] + b[i]
    desired_output.append(val)
```

More compactly, you could use list comprehension.

```
desired_output = [a[i % len(a)] + b[i] for i in range(len(b))]
```